# What are the main difference between 2 type of subscriptions in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

What are the difference between subscription and data driven subscription in SSRS?I have read about these two,but i didnt get the exact difference.both are scheduling,so both will be execution at scheduled time or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [data driven subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150.aspx) is dynamic.  This is directly from MSDN.  With a data driven subscription you can:

- Distribute a report to a fluctuating list of subscribers. For example, you can use data-driven subscriptions to distribute a report throughout a large organization where subscribers vary from one month to the next, or use other criteria that determines group membership from an existing set of users.
- Filter the report output using report parameter values that are retrieved at run time.
- Vary report output formats and delivery options for each report delivery.

Meanwhile... with a [standard subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155911%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) (again from MSDN) "the report consists of static values that cannot be varied during subscription processing. For each standard subscription, there is exactly one set of report presentation options, delivery options, and report parameters."